# How to Reset Counter when 5 is reached

Tags: php

can someone help me with a reset for a mysql counter. here is the code

```
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect to server "); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$counter=$rows['counter'];

// if have no counter value set counter = 1
if(empty($counter)){
$counter=1;
$sql1="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(counter) VALUES('$counter')";
$result1=mysql_query($sql1);
}

echo "You 're visitors No. ";
echo $counter;

// count more value
$addcounter=$counter+1;



// reset counter if 5 has been reached
If (counter==5){

echo "counter=5 ";
// now im getting an error here//
counter=0;
}


$sql2="update $tbl_name set counter='$addcounter'";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);

mysql_close();
?>

the error is:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\counter.php on line  
 and based on // counter=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the corrct working code.

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="gametest"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="counter"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect to server "); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$counter=$rows['counter'];

// if have no counter value set counter = 1
if(empty($counter)){
$counter=1;
$sql1="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(counter) VALUES('$counter')";
$result1=mysql_query($sql1);
}

echo "You 're visitors No. ";
echo $counter;

// count more value
$addcounter=$counter+1;


// reset counter if 5 has been reached
If ($counter==5){
$counter=0;
$addcounter=0;
}


$sql2="update $tbl_name set counter='$addcounter'";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);

mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 7):

you forgot *$*:

```
$counter=0;
```

*counter* on it's own is not a variable, additionally in your update query, you most likely after 0 value if you reached 5

```
If ($counter==5){
  echo "counter=5 ";
  $counter=0;
  $addcounter=0;
}
```

Comment: i tried, it removes the error but not resetting. any idea please

Comment: im kind of new here, how do i see your altered post?

Comment: I have just altered the reply, you need to reset $addcounter as well as $counter

Comment: please im getting lost, how can i do that. if you have the code it will really help

Comment: just have a look at the reply (I have just altered it), your sql query is "update $tbl_name set counter='$addcounter'"; but you not resetting $addcounter to 0; in the code I have added the line, that resets $addcounter = 0 if $counter==5;

Comment: ok i see. let me try it now. i will update you just now. thans so so much

Comment: yep its resetting but, its creating another row after it resets in the database